# How to execute a piece of code if the condition of a loop is not met?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a tree and I want to keep going left from the current node. And if there is no left from the current node, I wanna keep going right. otherwise return. To do something like that I'll have to write something like that:

```
if (node->left != nullptr)
    while (node->left != nullptr)
        node = node->left;
else if (node->right != nullptr)
    while (node->right != nullptr)
        node = node->right;
else return;
```

As you can see I had to write the condition twice. Can I write something like this:

```
while (node->left != nullptr)
    node = node->left;
else while (node->right != nullptr)
    node = node->right;
else return;
```

Also it would be helpful if I can use while with if. Something like this:

```
while (...) ...
else if (...) ... 
else while (...) ...
else ...
```

**Edit:**
Just realized that the example of trees is not a good one. But generally can I do something like that or not?

Comment: Just use the first example?

Comment: `while` does not return a boolean value, so it cannot be used for an `if` condition.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not saying to use it as a condition. I'm saying to use it along with ``if`` statements.

Comment: An `if` statement **requires** a condition.

Comment: @Kenwhite something like ``if (condition1) doSomething1 else while (condition2) doSomething2 else doSomething3``

Comment: Probably there's a way to get something like this with enough abuse of macros and lambdas and so on. Then you will have something you like, but nobody else can easily read.

Comment: @aschepler yeah, probably there is no other way. I was just asking whether something like that exists or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I mean, this will do what you are asking for

```
if (node->left != nullptr)
    while (node->left != nullptr)
        node = node->left;
else if (node->right != nullptr)
    while (node->right != nullptr)
        node = node->right;
else return;
```

but maybe is better to check that `node` is not `nullptr` (if you're not doing before)

```
if (node && node->left != nullptr)
    while (node->left != nullptr)
        node = node->left;
else if (node && node->right != nullptr)
    while (node->right != nullptr)
        node = node->right;
else return;
```

Comment: Not equivalent. What if after stepping left a number of times, it then steps right? The original steps either left some or right some, never both.

Comment: @aschepler sorry, from the question i've understood that you want first go straight left and then straight right, just after there is no more a left child

Comment: @aschepler but i mean, what's the point of the question?.. a "shorter way" to write those 3 lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible in this case. In fact, you can even avoid writing the `if` and `while` twice.

Notice that the only difference between the pieces of code, is *which* `Node` member is being used (i.e. are you branching left or right). So, depending on which branch you want to follow, you can take a pointer to that member, like this:

```
Node* Node::* branch = node->left != nullptr ? &Node::left : &Node::right;
```

and then unconditionally follow that branch, like this:

```
while (node->*branch != nullptr)
    node = node->*branch;
```

In general, when you have two identical pieces of code, you have to decide on a case by case basis which parts of it can be abstracted, and whether the resulting code is improved by it or not.